# How to add mvc view in visual studio 2019 as of it shows only razor view

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to add an mvc view in my controller but it only shows razor view while adding. Is i forget to install any packages???[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what you want.
**razor view** is different from **razor page**  .  **Razor view** is used for **mvc**